# Alternative phrase to use in place of "to support our claim ..."

Tags: word-choice

I am writing a paper where I face the following situation.

1) I have made a claim (something holds true when something else holds true)

2) To make my claim more concrete I follow the claim with experimental analysis.

I want to say something like "To make the claim concrete", we show the experimental results ...

I thought of using "to support our claim, ...", but that seems too mild. I want something more imposing.

Is there a way to say this more elegantly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"To validate" (does it match evidence? does it work in practice?) or "to verify" (does it behave? does it converge?), perhaps.

Answer (score 0):

'as evidenced by'is a good alternative.

Answer (score 0):

1) depending on context, you could replace claim with hypothesis or theory.

2) You could use any of the following verbs: establish, solidify, validate, defend

3) You can say it like this to emphasize that you are using an experiment to test it:

> to test and to establish

Or any of the other verbs.